# MemoryStore in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on implementing social network application using node.js and the source that I use is Building Node Application with MongoDB and Backbone' by Mike Wilson.However, I cannot figure out the how to resolve the error of the MemoryStore --var MemoryStore = require('connect').session.MemoryStore;
Also, I tried to comment it but the error with middleware appear
var Session = require('connect').middleware.session.Session;

Can I get your help please ?
Thanks in advance

Here is the code of app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var MemoryStore = require('connect').session.MemoryStore;
var dbPath = 'mongodb://10.168.122.123:27017/socialnet';
var fs = require('fs');
var events = require('events');

// Create an http server
app.server = http.createServer(app);

// Create an event dispatcher
var eventDispatcher = new events.EventEmitter();
app.addEventListener = function (eventName, callback) {
eventDispatcher.on(eventName, callback);
 };
app.removeEventListener = function (eventName, callback) {
eventDispatcher.removeListener(eventName, callback);
 };
app.triggerEvent = function (eventName, eventOptions) {
eventDispatcher.emit(eventName, eventOptions);
};

// Create a session store
app.sessionStore = new MemoryStore();

// Import the data layer
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = {
mail: require('./config/mail')
 };

// Import the model
var models = {
Account: require('./models/Account')(app, config, mongoose, nodemailer)
 }

// Configure the application
app.configure(function(){
app.sessionSecret = 'SocialNet secret key';
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.limit('1mb'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret:     app.sessionSecret,
    key:        'express.sid',
    store:      app.sessionStore
}));
mongoose.connect(dbPath, function onMongooseError(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
});

 // Import the routes located in ./routes
fs.readdirSync('routes').forEach(function(file) {
if (file[0] == '.') return;
var routeName = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
require('./routes/' + routeName)(app, models);
});

// -----
// GET /
// -----
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.render("index.jade", {layout: false});
 });

// -------------------
// POST /contacts/find
// -------------------
 app.post('/contacts/find', function(req, res) {
var searchStr = req.param('searchStr', null);

if (null == searchStr) {
    res.send(400);
    return;
}

models.Account.findByString(searchStr, function onSearchDone(err, accounts) {
    if (err || accounts.length == 0) {
        res.send(404);
    } else {
        // TODO: Check if these accounts were already contacts
        // if so, mark them as isContact so the views/Contact
        // knows not to add a addButton
        res.send(accounts);
    }
   });
  });

   // Let the server listen to 8000 (instead of the app)
   app.server.listen(8000);
   console.log('SocialNet listening to port 8000');
```

Comment: Please, add an exact error you're getting.

Comment: the error is:TypeError: Cannot read property 'MemoryStore' of undefined var MemoryStore =        require('connect').session.MemoryStore;
                                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MemoryStore' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/book-node-mongodb-backbone/ch10/app.js:5:45)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:124:16)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `require('connect').middleware.session.MemoryStore`?

Comment: What versions of `express` and `connect` are you using?

Comment: Anyway, `MemoryStore` is a default session store, so there is no need to explicitly specify it.

Comment: if I tried to comment the line of memory store and the line of middleware the application runs but I cannot add friends when I clicked on friends button

Comment: the node version is v0.11.14 and connect version is 2.0.0. express is 3.0.0

Comment: and I got an error that states var cookies = utils.parseSignedCookies(signedCookies,app.sessionSecret);TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseSignedCookies' of undefined. After I commented the MemeoryStore and middleware

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

> app.use(app.router)

, mounts your routes in that position in the call chain. You have it before your session middleware, so there is no req.session yet. When you leave it out, your routes will be positioned whenever you do your first app.get (or app.post and so on). If you still wish to control where your routes should be,

> you can just:

`move app.use(app.router) below the session middleware.`